# Local notification overriding silent mode (iOS 7)

Tags: ios, ios7, background, notifications, alarm

I know this question has been asked many times, but I was just wondering if now with iOS7 and the new background modes, **there is a trick to make a local notification sound when the device is in silent mode.**

I have an alarm app on the appstore (it is called wakeup challenge) and many of my users are complaining about this. I would really like to make that happen.

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Silent means silent.  The user is always right.